# Identify similarity in transformed geometric constructions programatically

Tags: math, geometry, coordinate-transformation

[image]

As shown in the image I have "shape1" and "shape2" separately. Both have same set of points A, B, C and D. Just by looking at those, shapes are different. But if you transform (rotate & translate) "shape2", you'll get "shape1". In other words, we can say "shape2" matches "shape1".

My question is, given 2 images with same points but different coordinates, how can I identify whether "shape2" matches "shape1" (or not) programatically?

PS: 
Both "shape1" and "shape2" will have same points A, B, C & D, but with different coordinates.
Possible transformations are rotating, translating or/and mirroring. No scaling applies.

I have seen there are methodologies to create transformed-shape with given-shape and a given-set-of-transformations. But this is kind of the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You did not display any code, so I also shall not and shall just discuss the algorithm.

One definition of similarity between two polygons is that **corresponding angles are equal and corresponding sides are proportional**. Therefore, start at two corresponding points, one on each polygon. For each polygon, record the ratio of the lengths of the line segments from those first points to the next points. Then continue around each polygon. Compare the oriented angles between consecutive segments--if any are not equal (or close enough in floating-point arithmetic), there is no similarity. Also compare ratios of corresponding segment lengths--if any of these ratios are not equal/close enough to the first, there is no similarity. If you get back to the first line segment and everything has checked, the polygons are similar.

Note that I assumed that you know what the corresponding points and orientations are. If this is not the case, you could repeat the procedure in the previous paragraph, twice for each point on one of the polygons (once for each orientation).

All that was to check *similarity*, as in your title. If you actually want to check for *congruence*, where "no scaling applies" as you state in the body of your question, the common ratio of line segment lengths must be one, and the algorithm is a little easier.

Is that algorithm clear? You must be able to find the length of a line segment and the oriented angle between two line segments given the coordinates, but you should know that kind of thing before you begin this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Measure the distance between each point and at least 3 other points. For 4 points, that means measure all 6 possible connections.

```
|A-B|, |A-C|, |A-D|, |B-C|, |B-D|, |C-D|
```

If I'm not mistaken, two quadrilaterals match if all those 6 lengths match. That's using your definition of match (translate, rotate, and mirror transformations only).

For N points you need ceil(N*1.5) connections/measurements. e.g. 5 points needs 8 connections, 6 points needs 9 connections.

To optimize, since you are only comparing, you can just calculate the squared distances and avoid many square roots.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to compute the transform that maps the points of one shape (the P[] below, there are N of them) most closely to the points of the other (the Q[]). This is known as the (orthogonal) Procrustes problem. If the resulting points are 'close enough' -- you may not get a perfect match because of the limited precision of floating point arithmetic -- you could say you have a match.

Here's the drill:

Compute the mean of the P's and subtract that from the P's, getting the p's say. Similarly subtract the mean (of the Q's) from the Q's.

Compute the 'covariance' matrix C of the p's and q's, that is:

```
C = Sum{ i | p[i]*q[i]' }/N
```

Compute the SVD of C, ie find orthogonal U, V and diagonal S so that

```
C = U*S*V'
```

The transform that best maps the P's to the Q's is then the (orthogonal) map

```
R = V*U'
```

and translation vector

```
T = Qbar - R*Pbar
```

where Qbar is the mean of the Q's, Pbar of the P's

However if you just want to know if there is transformation that makes the points match then you don't need to calculate R and T, all you need to calculate is the residual error, that is

```
E = Sum{ i | |Q[i] - P~[i]|^2 }/N
```

where the P~s are the Ps transformed by the transformation above, and |x| is the (Euclidean) norm of the vector x.

You can calculate E by

```
E = Sum{ i | |q[i]|^2 + |p[i]|^2}/N - 2*Tr(S)
```

Where Tr is the trace, ie the sum of the diagonal elements.

Comment: thank you @dmuir, I was searching for solution like this, kind of matrix transformation